# Designating a Fish Sponge?

Tags: halacha, fish

Rav Binyomin Forst writes in Laws of Kashrus (10:B:7)

> One must keep separate sponges for meat, dairy, and parve dishes,
> since actual food particles are absorbed into the sponges.

Since fish and meat residue mixed together is [potentially](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.116.2?vhe=Ashlei_Ravrevei:_Shulchan_Aruch_Yoreh_Deah,_Lemberg,_1888&lang=bi&with=Kaf%20HaChayim&lang2=en) a halachic issue to eat - which can then transfer the mixture when washing dishes. Although many [Poskim](https://outorah.org/p/27252/) don't require kashering a utensil with a mixture of meat and fish, they are careful not to mix the residue together lechatchila. Therefore, are we supposed to have a separate sponges for fish and meat?